# Certain Microsoft Extensions Displaying Version Compitability Errors In VSCodium

Tags: github-codespaces, vscodium

I understand many of Microsoft's and Github's extensions' licensing is not supposed to allow use of their extensions in anything but the official Visual Studio Code from Microsoft. However, it appears possible to install these even if it means [jumping through some hoops](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/1546#issuecomment-1741673730) even though some extensions such as Github Copilot work out of the box when install from their VSIX file. When I try to install something such as Remote Development - Devcontainers, Github Copilot Chat, or Github Codespaces, I get the error, "`Unable to install extension '<insert-extension-name-her>' as it is not compatible with VSCodium '1.83.1'.` " Is there any remedy or are the open source users stuck without necessary extensions?